# ListView: Null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview

Good day.  I'm having some issues with my android project specifically listview. I tried searching for other information here in this site, and implemented some of the answers. However, it is still not working.

The error specifically is

> NullPointerException at line 76 at MainActivity

Here is the code of my MainActivity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     final ArrayList<String> studentName = new ArrayList<String>();

     ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listName);

         aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, studentName);

         myList.setAdapter(aa);


        //droid.R.id.list;

        //add
        Button bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addstudent);
        bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ADDSTUDENTS"));
            }   
        });


        //edit

        Button bEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editstudent);
        bEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View x) {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.EDITSTUDENTS"));
            }
        });

        //edit

        Button bDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deletestudent);
        bDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View x) {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.DELETESTUDENTS"));
                }
            });


    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArray(){
        return studentName;
    }

    public void notifyArray(){
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and line 76 by the way is

```
aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my code for the AddStudents class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddStudents extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_student);

        Button bAddStudents = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.student_name);

        bAddStudents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity as = new MainActivity();

                as.getArray().add(et.getText().toString());
                as.notifyArray();
                finish();

            }   


        });

        Button bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backadd);

        bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();

            }   
    });


    }

}
```

and the xml part with the list view is

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listName" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </ListView>
```

I hope you can help me cause I want to also learn what my mistakes are. I can add other information if you want.

Comment: What are the values of your `studentName` arraylist? Have you added any values in your arraylist?

Comment: check this two link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817202/null-pointer-exception-during-android-listview-refresh

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894613/array-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-nullpointerexception-android

Comment: @Grishu I didn't add any values in the studentName array list. Cuase in my understanding, what im planning to do is that, when ever there is a new entry in the AddStudent class (when adding studens) , it automatically goes in the studentName arraylist. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `AddStudents` class, you're calling `notifyArray()` right after you instantiated `MainActivity`. `MainActivity.onCreate()` will not be called just by instantiating it.

Instantiating your `MainActivity` there is probably not what you want anyway (because that object will be disposed directly after the `onClick` handler is done).

What you want instead is to access the existing instance of `MainActivity`. For that, add a reference to the current instance to a static member of your `MainActivity` class, e.g.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static MainActivity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activity = this;
    }
}
```

Then in your `AddStudent` class access it via

```
MainActivity.activity.notifyArray()
```

This is not the most beautiful way to solve your issue, but it works as long as you can be sure to only have one `MainActivity` instance. (If not, you could make the array itself static; or create a Singleton wrapper class for it.)

Comment: sir, thanks for this explanation. I've understood the relationship now why it is not working (especially the arrangement). I tried nmw's answer and it worked but the list is not showing(seems like another problem in my list). I then tried your answer (codes) and the problem is that in the AddStudent class, it gives an error at MainActivity.activity.notifyArray().. specifically in the notifyArray part.

Comment: The method notifyArrays() is undefined for the type Activity. i double checked by the way, it has an s in the end.

Comment: I fixed it in the answer: the `activity` member needs to be of type `MainActivity`.

Comment: sir, the error is now gone. thanks! i have another problem though, if its fine with you. im also looking at it now. even though the error is gone, and when i click add it's fine. The listview is still not showing up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22327/discussion-between-domsom-and-newbielearner)

Answer (score 1):

`notifyArray()` is being called before `onCreate`.

Comment: adding the notifyArray() right before onCreate is giving an error that Unable to start activity... Null Pointer Exception

Comment: The position of the method isn't important, I said its being *called* before `onCreate()`. So you should look at where `notifyArray()` is being called from, and fix it so it is after `onCreate()`. Or just put a `if (aa != null)` check inside `notifyArray()` if you're lazy.

Comment: i understand. im sorry, i mistook ur first comment. looking at it now.

Comment: @domsom's answer also states this but provides much more info, so I'd follow that - and accept it if it solves the question.

Comment: @nmw i tried first your answer and it elimnated the error. The only problem now is that, even though it has updated... the list view is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling getArray().add(et.getText().toString()); and  notifyArray(); inside onResume() of MainActivity and NOT from AddStudentActivity( not recommended!)

So onResume() you would ideally want to add a new student to the list, so in your case, you can retrieve the student name using  a common sharable object like a hashtable or somethiing similar, make it a singleton, and use it from anywhere in the applciation

The common class may go something like:

```
class CommonHashtable{

private static Hashtable<String, Object> commonHashtable = null;

public static getInstance(){
    if(commonHashtable == null)
        commonHashtable = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

    return commonHashtable;
}
```

on getInstance(), it returns a commonHashtable which can be used to store values temporarily!

so, add this on addbutton click event

```
Hashtable hash = CommonHashtable.getInstance();
hash.put("NEW_STUDENT_NAME", et.getText().toString());
```

and add this in you onResume() of MainActivity

```
Hashtable hash = CommonHashtable.getInstance();
Object studentName = (String) hash.get("NEW_STUDENT_NAME");

if(studentName != null){
    notifyArray();
}
```

Comment: Architecture-wise I'd not recommend this: It introduces an implicit data-based dependency and code cluttering where not necessary. My two cents: If you're leaving the data manipulation in `StudentClass` and only move the notification to `MainActivity`, then either use a broadcast intent to trigger that or call `notifyArray()` in `MainActivity.onResume()` unconditionally.